# HTML5 Video Stuck in One Position at Edge of Screen

Tags: javascript, css, cordova, wkwebview, p5.js

I'm running into this issue on webkit, specifically web view on iOS. I tested this on desktop Chrome and did not experience this issue.

[Portrait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOf0t.jpg) and
[Landscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Omdz.png)

Essentially the video is stuck in one spot no matter where I scroll. I can't see the full video or scroll in the area of the video to see the rest of the video feed.

I believe this is a  problem with Webkit and my poor CSS skills. I'm using latest Cordova, WKWebView, P5.js, and a Cordova iOS RTC plugin to stream the video into P5. Would appreciate any help on this!

```
      p.createCanvas(640, 480);
      video = p.createCapture(p.VIDEO);
      console.log("video", video);
      video.size(640, 480);
      video.attribute("autoplay", "autoplay");
      video.attribute("playsinline", "playsinline");
      video.attribute("muted", "muted");
      p.image(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is caused because of `p.createCanvas(640, 480)`.
When you create a video element with p5, it doesn't seem to use the **canvas** element but the HTML **video** instead. So the canvas element you created just occcupies space and the video element is pushed down in natural order.

So, try this instead and let me know if this fixes your issue:

```
p.createCanvas(0, 0)
```